# Json schema in draftv3

Tags: json, jsonschema

Request:

```
{
  "PersonSearch":
  {
    "LastName": "Doe",
    "Gender":"Male",
    "State" : "FL"
   }
}
```

or

```
{
  "PersonSearch":
   {
    "FirstName": "John",
    "Gender":"Male",
    "State" : "FL"
   }
}
```

What is the json schema that I can validate both requests.
It has to be compatible with drraftV3.

Comment: Hold on. Are they the same format? Looks good to me.

Answer (score 0):

Your requirements seem to be that you need *either* `"FirstName"` or `"LastName"`, correct?

There is no way to specify a single schema that works for both v4 and v3, because of some fundamental changes in the spec: in v4 `type` can only hold a string (or array of strings).  It is not permitted to use schemas inside `type`.

You should avoid using v3 if possible, and move over to v4.

### v4 method:

In that case, you'll need to use `anyOf` for that particular constraint:

```
{
    "type": "object",
    "anyOf": [
        {"required": ["FirstName"]},
        {"required": ["LastName"]}
    ],
    "properties": {...}
}
```

### v3

In v3 syntax, you use `type` instead of `anyOf` (also, `required` is a boolean):

```
{
    "type": [
        {
            "type": "object",
            "properties": {
                "FirstName": {"required": true}
            }
        },
        {
            "type": "object",
            "properties": {
                "LastName": {"required": true}
            }
        }
    ],
    "properties": {...}
}
```

### v3 -> v4 conversion

If you're stuck with a mixture of v3/v4 schemas, [this tool (json-schema-compatibility)](https://github.com/geraintluff/json-schema-compatibility) will normalise schemas (v3 or v4) into v4 syntax.

If you're working in JavaScript, you can run the schemas through the compatibility tool before you use them.  You can then use purely v4-tools for your actual validation/whatever.

Comment: I need in just draftv3. Bcoz we didn't move yet to v4

Comment: `{"type":"object",
"additionalProperties":false,
"properties":{"PersonSearch":{
"required":true,"type":[{"required": ["FirstName"]},
     {"required": ["LastName"]}]}},
"FirstName":{"type":"object","additionalProperties":false,
"properties":{"FirstName":{"type":"string","required":true},
"Gender":{"type":"string","required":true},
"state":{"type":"string","required":true}}},
"LastName":{"type":"object","additionalProperties":false,
"properties":{"LastName":{"type":"string","required":true},
"Gender":{"type":"string","required":true},
"state":{"type":"string","required":true}}}` Is this right

Comment: I've fleshed out the examples.

I'm afraid your code is not correct.  You have mis-used `required` (it must be a boolean in v3, and have also done something strange with sub-schemas.  Were you trying to reference the sub-schemas?

Comment: Could you pls share the schema that is only valid in draft3?

Comment: I have shared it, under the "v3" section.  It uses an array of schemas inside `type`, which is disallowed in v4.